# Find the longest arithmetic progression from an array

Tags: c

I have an array of numbers ex.[5,1,2,4,6,8,12], and I want to find the length of longest arithmetic progression within the sequence and to print it. Longest arithmetic progression means an increasing sequence with common difference, in this case [2,4,6,8].

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int array[100], i, num,diff;
    printf("Enter the size of an array \n");

    scanf("%d", &num);

    printf("Enter the elements of the array \n");

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }

    printf("\n Numbers in a.p: ");

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        diff = array[i+1]-array[i];
        if (array[i]-diff == array[i+1]-diff);
        {
            printf("%d, ", array[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n Common difference:%d", diff);
}
```

Comment: Show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Sounds like a decent challenge . Best of luck ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm voting to close this question as this is clearly a write my code request without any visible effort from Cristi Wolf, not a _question_.

Comment: Kindly show your research / debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: And where is your problem with it?

Comment: What is your code expected to do, and what is it doing instead?

Comment: It's expected to print the longest arithmetic progression, and it is printing the all numbers from array.

Comment: If user enters more than 100 numbers, you are out of bounds for the array access. If user enters trash you end up in an ugly loop. `array[i]+1==array[i]+diff`does not look convincing. I think you might want to swap the two statements in the loop.

Comment: Give sample input you are using.

Comment: `array[i+1]` will yield _IndexOutOfBounds_. Anyway you probably meant `array[i - 1]` (and the index error is still on). Also `array[i]+1` should probably be `array[i + 1]`. Considering the above, you should traverse the array from 1 to `num - 1` (not from 0 to `num`).

Comment: Check return value of scanf.

Comment: Sample input: 5,1,2,4,6,8,12. And it should print: 2,4,6,8 but prints 5,1,2,4,6,8,12.

Comment: Compile your code with more warnings, e.g. `gcc -Wall`. Fix them or explain why you think they are no problem.

Comment: When `i = num - 1` what is `array[i+1]`? Isn't that *Undefined Behavior*? Better `for (i = 1; i < num; i++)` and compare `array[i - 1]` and `array[i]`..

Comment: Code updated.The program prints the array, without checking if the numbers are in arithmetic progression. I think the problem is in the if statement, if someone will figure it out please help me with the code.

Comment: The biggest problem is **behind** the if condition, the `;`.

Comment: @CristiWolf You can 'brute force' a solution with a loop over the *start index* (`0 -> num-1`) with an inner loop where you check `diff` from (`1 -> num-1`) computing and saving the *start index*, *progression length*, and *diff*. Your solution will be the combination that gives the longest *progression length*. (you can optimize by breaking out of the loops when `longest progression >= num / diff`, hint a `goto` is a useful tool to `break` out of nested loops). Good luck.

Comment: Can the longest AP sequence be non-contiguos as well ?

Comment: If you put the sample input into the question instead of into a comment, the downvote (not by me) might disappear. [mcve] with sample input is better appreciated than without.

Comment: see this for more detailed answer with test unit test https://github.com/shivabhusal/algorithms/blob/master/common_algos/longest_arithmetic_progression.c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this seems to be a homework or challenge I will only help by solving your immediate problems, caused by very strange code.
Here is code which at leat detects the progressions correctly.
You can yourself count the length, store the longest length and its index, then print that sequence after parsing all the array.
There are two assumptions here, which you might want to avoid for challenge/homework:

- no identical numbers entered
- no overlapping progressions,
  i.e. no number is the last of one and the first of next progression

The representation of more than one sequence in the output is a little jittery (missing ")"), but that is not relevant for finding and exclusively printing the longest one.
I did not bother about your ratio output, no idea what that is supposed to be.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// avoid a warning
int main() {
    int array[100], i, num, diff=0, lastdiff=0, first=1;

    printf("Enter the size of an array \n");

    // for good code, this should check the result
    scanf("%d", &num);
    // in case of scaf-failure, cleanup here for good code

    // asking for the number of elements
    // and then relying on that number to be entered
    // is less elegant than checking for and end condition
    // like EOF or negative input

    printf("Enter the elements of the array \n");
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        // for good code, this should check the result
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
        // in case of scaf-failure, cleanup here for good code
    }
    printf("\n Numbers in a.p: ");
    for (i = 1; i < num; i++) {

        lastdiff=diff;
        diff = array[i]-array[i-1];
        if (diff==lastdiff)
        {   if(first==1)
            { first=0;
                printf("(%d, %d",array[i-2], array[i-1]);
            }
            printf(", %d", array[i]);
        } else
        {   first=1;
        }
    }
    printf(")\n Ratio:%d", diff);

    // avoid a warning
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, it was a challenge and I am beginner in C programming.

Comment: Mentioning that directly would be appreciated for future questions. Good luck.

Comment: @Yunnosch Thanks for the tip. Good luck for you too!

Comment: @BLUEPIXY It works for sample input. It has some assumptions and a little representation issue, as described inside the answer. For what does it not work?

Comment: try ex `[5,1,2,4,6,8,12]` and `[5,1,2,3,4,6,8,12]`

Comment: Is the first 5 the number of entries? Can you describe the specialty your sequences have?

Comment: [1st DEMO](http://ideone.com/DhG0no) See `Ratio:4`,  [2nd DEMO](http://ideone.com/jMqeMs) `Numbers in a.p: (1, 2, 3, 4(4, 6, 8)
 Ratio:4` ??

Comment: The numbers 1,2,3,4 and 4,6,8 are in arithmetic progression.

Comment: Actually 1,2,3,4 and 4,6,8 which are detected and represented (badly but not wrongly) as `(1, 2, 3, 4(4, 6, 8)`.

Comment: I did not bother about the ratio. Is that the part you question?

Comment: The question was only about the a.p, the ratio was a bonus in code.

Comment: _Longest arithmetic progression means an increasing sequence with common difference_

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I did not handle the "longest" part. Leaving it to OP to complete the challenge. Please describe what the conflict is that you see. I fail to deduce it from your examples and quotes.

Answer (score 1):

like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
#if DEBUG
    int array[] = {5,1,2,4,6,8,12};
    int num = sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array);
    int i, diff;
#else
    int array[100], i, num,diff;
    printf("Enter the size of an array \n");

    scanf("%d", &num);

    printf("Enter the elements of the array \n");

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }
#endif
    int j, len, longest_len = 2, longest_i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < num - longest_len; i += len-1) {
        diff = array[i+1]-array[i];
        for(j = i+2; j < num && array[j-1]+diff == array[j]; ++j);
        len = j - i;
        if(longest_len < len){
            longest_len = len;
            longest_i = i;
        }
    }
    printf("\n Numbers in a.p: ");
    diff = array[longest_i+1] - array[longest_i];
    printf("[ ");
    for(i = 0; i < longest_len; ++i){
        printf("%d", array[longest_i + i]);
        if(i == longest_len-1)
            printf(" ]\n");
        else
            printf(", ");
    }
    printf("\n Common difference:%d", diff);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @BLUEPIXY !

Comment: It is assumed that the length of the sequence is 2 or more. If it is 1 or less, the problem is meaningless. You probably need to check the user's input.

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of ways to approach this challenge. You can either check each diff against each value in the array or work the other way around. Given you are not sorting the values, you may benefit by nesting the check of values within your loop over all possible `diffs`. Something similar to the following works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int a[] = {5, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 12},
        n = sizeof a / sizeof *a,
        startidx = 0,
        maxlen = 0;

    for (int d = 1; d < n; d++) {       /* loop over diffs */
        int idx = -1,
            len = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)     /* loop over values */
            if (a[i - 1] + d == a[i]) {
                if (idx < 0)            /* if index not set */
                    idx = i - 1;        /* set to 1st index */
                len++;                  /* increment length */
            }
        if (idx >= 0 && len > maxlen) { /* if progression found */
            maxlen = len;               /* save length */
            startidx = idx;             /* save start index */
        }
    }

    printf ("longest progression: '%d' elements.\n", maxlen);
    for (int i = 0; i < maxlen; i++)
        printf (i ? ", %d" : "%d", a[startidx + i]);
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/maxprogression
longest progression: '4' elements.
2, 4, 6, 8
```

Investigate several ways to approach it, and finally settle on the one that makes the most sense to you. You can work on optimizing later.

As far as the code you posted goes, *always* validate all user input by, at minimum, checking that the number of expected conversions to type took place, e.g.

```
if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1) {
    fprintf (stderr, "error: input conversion failed for 'num'.\n");
    return 1;
}
```

You would do the same in your values loop. Let me know if you have any questions. Good luck with your coding.

Comment: Looping over all possible diffs (with a nested loop inside) is a, hmmm, very *individual* approach. It makes a big difference in speed, O(n*n) instead of O(n).

Comment: Agreed, that's why the optimization comment was left to later. This is simply a 'brute force' example of an alternative.

Answer (score -1):

Following is the complete working code. You can see it working [here](http://ideone.com/EfLiT9):

```
     #include <stdio.h>

 int main()
 {
     int array[100], i, num,diff, resDiff, startIndx, resStartIndx, countCur, countPre;
     printf("Enter the size of an array \n");
     scanf("%d", &num);

     printf("Enter the elements of the array \n");
     for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
         scanf("%d", &array[i]);
     }

     //Now code changes
     startIndx =0, resStartIndx=0, countPre=0, resDiff=0;
     for (i = 0; i < num; /*No increment required here*/) {
         countCur =0;
         startIndx=i;
         countCur++;

         if(++i < num)
         {
             diff = array[i] - array[startIndx];
             countCur++;
             i++;
             while((i < num) && (diff == (array[i] - array[i-1])))
             {
                 countCur++;
                 i++;
             }

             if(countCur > countPre)
             {
                 resStartIndx = startIndx;
                 countPre = countCur;
                 resDiff = diff;
             }
         }
     }

     countPre += resStartIndx;
     printf("\n Numbers in a.p: ");
     for (i = resStartIndx; i < countPre; i++) {
         printf("%d, ", array[i]);
     }
     printf("\n Common difference:%d", resDiff);
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: It's a good method to find the longest a.p without increment. Thanks!